# How to make a rectangle by aligning the cloud of points obtained with four lidars?

Tags: alignment, point-cloud-library

I have 4 laserscan data that measured blocks using four 2D-LiDAR in ROS.

LiDAR measures as it descends, so its appearance is divided by vibration.

In this situation, I would like to sort the data to obtain a complete square shape using an **algorithm**.

[image]

I will be so glad if you give me some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that your manual measurements for constructing the tf's are accurate, you might need to perform a sensor calibration. Your sensor might be giving measurements with a fixed error, namely, bias or offset. For example they might be measuring a 20 cm distance as 21 cm.